# Alpha component ignored error

Tags: javascript, css, colors, three.js

This is the code that I have at the moment

```
var getColor = $(".test").css('Color');
material.color.setStyle(getColor);
```

While this is working for me, sometimes upon refreshing the page, the sprite color wouldn't show up. The error I'd receive is: `THREE.Color: Alpha component of ' + style + '`, which is strange since I don't have any.

Full code [here](http://codepen.io/lexa-r/pen/jyOoLa).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT:** Clarification.

Comment: Looks like it's working fine -- are you getting any errors?

Comment: @furkle It doesn't happen a lot but what I'd get is `THREE.Color: Alpha component of ' + style + ' will be ignored.`

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I think that might be a little outside my expertise -- hopefully someone else will have the domain knowledge to get why that happens sometimes but not other times.

Comment: @furkle Ah, alright. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right from the documentation about `.setStyle()` method: _Transluent colors such as "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)" and "hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.5)" are also accepted, but the alpha-channel coordinate will be discarded._

Comment: @prisoner849 The thing is, I didn't put any alpha component. As you can see from my code, it's only the RGB hex value.

Comment: The pen doesn't reproduce the issue, it seems.

Comment: @StefanDragnev That's really strange because I didn't alter the code, they're the exact same lines as the one I have.